# Flex:Item Renderer for a whole Grid row?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I have a AdvancedDataGrid object on which i wish to have item renderer which is another grid, which to show when i click on the corresponding row.

[image]

- How to make such a renderer ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Usually rows are "shown" by itemRenderers by default.  Why would they need to click anything?

Comment: if i use an item renderer each cell will became a grid, i need the row to became a grid, but only when double clicked to expand into a grid, else it shall look like a normal row filled with different data.

Comment: Maybe some screenshots or mockups of what you want to accomplish would help me understand.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please tell me if there is something else which can help to find a solution on the question.

Comment: I don't think it's possible within any kind of Flex DataGrid. The only solution I can come up with is a popup that you position exactly over the selected row. I'm also not sure if this makes much sense from a usabilty point of view...

Comment: it is written currently as application in C# which i am translating into Flex. and the usability is choosen by the clients to be this way :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following link. This helps you.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bf2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf65e9f-7fd4